# Docker: gradle build without copying source from host

Tags: docker, gradle, build

Docker: gradle build without copying source from host?

```
FROM gradle:8.0.2-jdk11-alpine
WORKDIR /app/src
COPY . .
RUN gradle assemble
```

If the source is huge, is there a way to link /app/src to the source on host instead of "copy"? This would speed up docker image build.

The source will not be in the final image, so it is not necessary to pull source into the image.